# Getting error when inserting details from the event registration page

Tags: calendar-events

{exp:proform:form} could not insert into form: event_registration. After clicking on event registration after entering the details, when I click on "Submit" it is giving error.

URL :

http://www.bethesomebody.org/calendar/primary-families

Comment: Hi, I am go to your URL adding the details submit the form the page submit loading without error, what is the error you see??

Comment: But I am getting the below error    Error

{exp:proform:form} could not insert into form: event_registration

Comment: maybe because you login as superadmin

Comment: I found this post http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/proform-drag-and-drop-form-builder/viewthread/6091  I don't know if this will help you